# grub2-bios-setup: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible

Tags: linux, boot, grub, gpt

Grub2 won't install on a hdd with GPT partition label (without --force), complaining about a missing BIOS boot partion - even though there is one.
The first partition (1 MB) is supposed to be used as BIOS boot partition.

Why can't the Grub installer find it?

> ## grub2-install --boot-directory=BOOT/grub2 /dev/sda
>
> /usr/sbin/grub2-bios-setup: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
> /usr/sbin/grub2-bios-setup: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
> /usr/sbin/grub2-bios-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
>
> ## parted /dev/sda unit B print
>
> Model: VMware, VMware Virtual S (scsi)
> Disk /dev/sda: 53687091200B
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
> Partition Table: gpt
> Disk Flags: pmbr_boot
>
> Number  Start         End           Size          File system     Name  Flags
> 1      1048576B      2097151B      1048576B
> 2      2097152B      526385151B    524288000B    ext2
> 3      526385152B    27369930751B  26843545600B  ext4
> 4      27369930752B  32738639871B  5368709120B   linux-swap(v1)
> 5      32738639872B  53686042623B  20947402752B  ext4
>
> ## sgdisk -p /dev/sda
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 104857600 sectors, 50.0 GiB
> Logical sector size: 512 bytes
> Disk identifier (GUID): F4679BF9-DC8C-4346-8889-83B84F43BE58
> Partition table holds up to 128 entries
> First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 104857566
> Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
> Total free space is 4029 sectors (2.0 MiB)
>
> Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
> 1            2048            4095   1024.0 KiB  0700
> 2            4096         1028095   500.0 MiB   0700
> 3         1028096        53456895   25.0 GiB    0700
> 4        53456896        63942655   5.0 GiB     0700
> 5        63942656       104855551   19.5 GiB    0700
>
> ## sgdisk -i 1 /dev/sda
>
> Partition GUID code: EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 (Microsoft basic data)
> Partition unique GUID: 075D0E05-FC7B-482C-9BF8-0FD0A83D02F5
> First sector: 2048 (at 1024.0 KiB)
> Last sector: 4095 (at 2.0 MiB)
> Partition size: 2048 sectors (1024.0 KiB)
> Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
> Partition name: ''
>
> ## sgdisk -i 2 /dev/sda
>
> Partition GUID code: EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 (Microsoft basic data)
> Partition unique GUID: 51756103-CDA5-4D09-BFB4-B1DB8A89CE08
> First sector: 4096 (at 2.0 MiB)
> Last sector: 1028095 (at 502.0 MiB)
> Partition size: 1024000 sectors (500.0 MiB)
> Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
> Partition name: ''
>
> ## sgdisk -i 3 /dev/sda
>
> Partition GUID code: EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 (Microsoft basic data)
> Partition unique GUID: 2A6E6859-DCE0-4040-8683-15B51A3F0911
> First sector: 1028096 (at 502.0 MiB)
> Last sector: 53456895 (at 25.5 GiB)
> Partition size: 52428800 sectors (25.0 GiB)
> Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
> Partition name: ''
>
> ## sgdisk -i 4 /dev/sda
>
> Partition GUID code: EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 (Microsoft basic data)
> Partition unique GUID: 0CBCDEFE-9467-4534-9EE2-7C142CCD3B09
> First sector: 53456896 (at 25.5 GiB)
> Last sector: 63942655 (at 30.5 GiB)
> Partition size: 10485760 sectors (5.0 GiB)
> Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
> Partition name: ''
>
> ## sgdisk -i 5 /dev/sda
>
> Partition GUID code: EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 (Microsoft basic data)
> Partition unique GUID: 22C44A3F-B738-4050-8AD5-0556750A074B
> First sector: 63942656 (at 30.5 GiB)
> Last sector: 104855551 (at 50.0 GiB)
> Partition size: 40912896 sectors (19.5 GiB)
> Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
> Partition name: ''

Comment: If you [edit] your question and put the individual partition type GUIDs in, answerers will be able to tell you why.

Comment: @JdeBP I have included additional info in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The first partition (1 MB) is supposed to be used as BIOS boot partition.

But, as you can see, it isn't.  All of your partitions are MS Basic Data partitions, type EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7.  GRUB's so-called "BIOS Boot Partition" (a rather misleading name as this partition is not understood or used by the actual machine firmware) is type 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649 (an invalid GUID).

That's the partition type that GRUB is looking for.  You don't have one of that type.  Hence the error message saying so.  It's as simple as that.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). ["Non-system special volumes"](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/boot-and-system-volumes.html#NonSystemVolumes). *What "boot" and "system" volumes are*. Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: That's it, I forgot to set the bios_grub flag. Thanks.